# Can I have a raised edge on a layout or component box?

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android application and I have a box within a box on my UI. I changed the color of the backgrounds so the user can differentiate them. However, I want to know if I can have a raise edge or different color "edge" of a layout.

```
+_____________+
|   _______   |
|   |      |  |
|   |      |  |
|   |______|  |
+_____________+
```

Imagine that horrible box is the screen, and the outer box has a background of white and the inner box's background is blue. Can I can make the 'edges' a different color and appear raised so the user can see a a better distinction between the boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create your own background drawable for your View. I invite you to read about 9-patches and how to create them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to create a background image the way you like. 9 patch is the way to go, I think. Also you can consider other types of drawables: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using one of the backgrounds built into Honeycomb for this.  Not exactly what you're asking for but I think it does a good job separating the areas.  Set the background of your view to:

`android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground"`

And the end result is on the right pane:

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-jTDarHrqACg/TV4qSsfBH8I/AAAAAAAAAEI/-N5mOnVv_-s/s1600/pic-2.png

But if you want it to work on pre-Honeycomb devices you'll have to take the background drawable, which is a small 9 patch, and use it as a resource in your project.  It can be found in your SDK at `platforms/android-13/data/res/drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-hdpi`

Comment: That looks fantastic-- yea I hope to work on as many phones as possible. Thanks, I will give this a shot tonight!